# Extending data models within a MicroService architecture

Tags: database, microservices

As part of a personal research project, I'm attempting to learn more about Microservice architecture and how to incorporate it within the industry I work with.

I've been reading a lot of booked and articles around Microservice architecture, and have been researching and working with multiple different software components to support this architecture, such as RabbitMQ, however I have come unstuck at initiation of the data models.

To put the requirement in it's simplest form, lets say I have the requirement for two Microservices for the following high level requirement (please note, I am excluding the WebAPI / Bridge microservice and UI microservices as part of this process, I am just focusing on the backend Microservices that house core data):

## Requirement:

Provide the ability for a customer to log into a portal and add register for a "scheme", which allows them to add money or credit to their record.  This will be a multi-tenanted solution, where data can be placed in a single database or over multiple databases (already covered) and each Microservice will be responsible for it's own table(s).

Some "tenants" may or may not have the "Credit Microservice" enabled as defined below and may only have the "Customer Microservice" and potentially other Microservices such as "Marketing Microservice" (not defined below, but referenced as an example)

### Customer Microservice:

Responsible for managing customer information within the system, such as First Name, Last name, email address, etc.   This Microservice will expose various functions such as Creating a new Customer, Updating an Existing customer, Deleting a customer and finally retrieving customers (Basic CRUD operations).

This Microservice will be fed data directly from our internal CRM (Customer Relationship Management) system via integration (this part is covered)

Data Scheme:

- CustomerId
- FirstName
- LastName
- EmailAddress

Once a customer is created, an event is posted on the message queue informing other microservices that a Customer has been created.

### Credit Microservice:

Responsible for managing a customers balance and scheme enrolled within.  By default, a customer will NOT be enrolled in a scheme, and will therefore NOT be able to deposit credit to their account.

This Microservice will expose functions to "Enroll" a member to a scheme and "AddCredit" to their account as well as retrieving the information for a particular customer (their scheme and balance).  In real life, this would also let them change scheme, and have various other options, but I'm keeping that out of this for this simple example.

Within the system, this Microservice would likely be responsible for storing the "transactions" to credit as well, in a separate table within it's database (or unique schema within a single database instance).  This is not defined below as it is irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Data Scheme:

- CustomerId
- SchemeName
- Balance

This Microservice will be responsible for listening to events from the Customer Microservice and creating new customers within it's own unique SQL table, allowing that customer to Enrol or Add Credit to their account.

## Issue:

Within the UI element of the application, I need to show admin users a list of customers, including if they are enrolled in the application or not, as well as how much credit the customer has, but only if they have enabled the "Credit" functionality (the identification of this is already covered, each tenant can enable certain Microservices when setup)

The issue comes in the fact that the data is stored over two tables, and mastered by two different Microservices...

Do I create a new Microservice (EG:  CustomerCredit) that joins the two tables together (readonly) to display the results?   Does the API call the Customer Microservice "retrieve" first then call the Credit Microservice "retrieve" after with the relevant IDs and then join them together?

The first example above does not work in practice, as I might have MULTIPLE microservices extending the schema of the customer model, for example, Marketing where I might store "Last Email Date" against a customer id.

EDIT:

To confirm, the structure would look similar to the below:

[image: Microservice Structure]

Comment: I'll be interested to see the answers as I don't fully know the 'right' way forward, although one point: a [database per microservice](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html) makes sense, but a microservice per _table_ sounds like your microservices might be a bit too granular?

But putting that point to one side, a microservice for core customer information, and then a single microservice managing both credit + customer credit would make sense. This latter 'credit microservice' will therefore provide _all_ functions relating to credit, including customer-credit.

Comment: Hey- sorry I will reread through my question, as that was not my intention, a single microservice may have multiple tables, that they master (basically, it's exactly the same as having a single database per microservice, apart from instead, they only have access to their own tables within a single database).